# How to apply cache tags to template file?

Tags: cache, secure, cache-tag

I am trying to implement a cache key to automatically change when URL is changed from secure `(https://) to unsecure (http://)` or vice versa

but I am missing something out that is causing the `CACHE_KEY` to not work.

Here is what I have tried so far:

Block class

Here I define the cache_key and cache_tag and check if store `isCurrentlySecure`

```
const CACHE_TAG = 'top_switcher';
const CACHE_KEY = 'currency_switcher';

protected function _construct()
{
    $this->_secure = Mage::app()->getStore()->isCurrentlySecure();
    $this->addData(
        array (
            'cache_tags' => array(self::CACHE_TAG),
            'cache_key' => array(self::CACHE_KEY),
        )
    );
    parent::_construct();

}
```

Next my cache_key info

```
public function getCacheKeyInfo()
{
    return array(
        'switch_container_content',
        (int)Mage::app()->getStore()->isCurrentlySecure(),
        Mage::getUrl('locale/switch', array('_secure' => true)),
        $this->_secure,
    );
}
```

Here I would like to switch to secure https:

```
public function getSwitchUrl()
{

    $currentUrl = (int)Mage::app()->getStore()->isCurrentlySecure() ?
            Mage::getUrl('module/switch', array('_secure' => true)) : Mage::getUrl('locale/switch');

    return $currentUrl;


}
```

In my form which is used to post data over secure and unsecure pages I add the `<form method="post" action="<?php echo $this->getSwitchUrl(); ?>">`

Can anyone tell me what I have done incorrectly?